# Determine Matching Pairs of Rows in DataFrame and Showcase Pass/Fail

Tags: python, openpyxl

I have a DataFrame containing pairs of rows (Source and Target), and I want to determine whether each pair is matching. I need to add a new column to indicate if the pair passes or fails the matching condition.

```
Obs | Dataset | Col1 | Col2 | Col3
----------------------------------
1   | Source  | A    | 10   | X
2   | Target  | A    | 10   | X
3   | Source  | B    | 20   | Y
4   | Target  | B    | 20   | Y
5   | Source  | C    | 30   | Z
6   | Target  | D    | 30   | Z
```

Output I want:

```
Obs | Dataset | Result | Col1 | Col2 | Col3
--------------------------------------------
1   | Source  | Pass   | A    | 10   | X
2   | Target  |        | A    | 10   | X
3   | Source  | Pass   | B    | 20   | Y
4   | Target  |        | B    | 20   | Y
5   | Source  | Fail   | C    | 30   | Z
6   | Target  |        | D    | 30   | Z
```

Code:

import pandas as pd
from openpyxl import load_workbook
from openpyxl.styles import PatternFill

class ExcelHighlighter:
def **init**(self, file_path, sheet_name):
self.file_path = file_path
self.sheet_name = sheet_name
self.light_green_fill = PatternFill(start_color='00FF00', end_color='00FF00', fill_type='solid')
self.light_coral_fill = PatternFill(start_color='FF8080', end_color='FF8080', fill_type='solid')

```
def highlight_and_save(self, output_path='output.xlsx'):
    df = pd.read_excel(self.file_path, sheet_name=self.sheet_name)

    with pd.ExcelWriter(output_path, engine='openpyxl') as writer:
        df.to_excel(writer, index=False, sheet_name=self.sheet_name)
        workbook = writer.book
        sheet = writer.sheets[self.sheet_name]

        for row in range(2, df.shape[0] + 1, 2):
            for col in range(3, df.shape[1]):
                cell_value_source = df.iloc[row - 2, col]
                cell_value_target = df.iloc[row - 1, col]

                if cell_value_source != cell_value_target:
                    sheet.cell(row=row - 1, column=col + 1).fill = self.light_coral_fill
                    sheet.cell(row=row, column=col + 1).fill = self.light_coral_fill

        df['Result'] = ''

        for row in range(2, df.shape[0] + 1, 2):
            for col in range(3, df.shape[1]):
                cell_value_source = df.iloc[row - 2, col]
                cell_value_target = df.iloc[row - 1, col]

                if cell_value_source == cell_value_target:
                    # Set 'Pass' in the 'Result' column for both Source and Target
                    df.at[row - 1, 'Result'] = 'Pass'
                    df.at[row, 'Result'] = 'Pass'

                elif cell_value_source != cell_value_target:
                    # Set 'Fail' in the 'Result' column for both Source and Target
                    df.at[row - 1, 'Result'] = 'Fail'
                    df.at[row, 'Result'] = 'Fail'

        df = pd.concat([df.iloc[:, :3], df['Result'], df.iloc[:, 3:-1]], axis=1)

        workbook.save(output_path)
```

Expectation is here how I can add 'Result'(as the 3rd column)?

Comment: Your problem is underspecified. .. The easiest way would be to split it into 2 separate dataframes (say `source_df` and `target_df`) and then just run an `equals` operation.. that will compare all rows. The problem is that you don't have an exact index to compare on! The only thing you can do is to find all rows that exist in both (= "pass") and report all that don't have any match ("fail").

Answer (score 0):

The solution lies in identifying all that "pass" (i.e., that are present in 'source' and in 'target'), and defining all others as "fail".

```
# break up the input into 2 separate dataframes
source_df = df[df['Dataset'] == 'Source']
target_df = df[df['Dataset'] == 'Target']

# apply pd.merge, which will only keep those records that are prsent in both
pass_df = pd.merge(source_df, taget_df, how='inner', on=['Col1', 'Col2', 'Col3'])
```

All others are "fail".

In your original problem, you want to write "pass" or "fail" only on one row (the one from source) - that's a bit weird to be honest, as "fail" is not defined. Imagine you have rows in target which don't exist in source.. would those be "fail" too? It seems to me that "pass"/"fail" is really a property of the combined set, not just of "source". So unless you define a bit more precisely how to handle "mismatches", I believe your (implicit) definition is that "fail" is anything that's not "pass", with "pass" being a duplicate in "Source" and "Target". And while - of course - you can save the info back into only the "source" df, - the logic what defines a "fail" may produce records that are just not present in source, but only in target - so how would you handle those records?

Comment: Hi @KingOtto, Thank you for your help i tried the modified code but not sure why its Result column is coming as blank could you please help me out?

Comment: by modified code you mean my suggested answer? in there, I don't save the information into the "Results" col, but rather into a new dataframe "pass_df" that holds all records with a "pass". As explained in my reply, I did not feel like it is possible to save it back into the original df as long as you don't have an exact definition for "fail"

Comment: no i tried another way can you please check what is wrong in my solution?

Comment: No. Please try the code that I shared. Does that produce the desired output? Without your test xlsx input file, I cannot run your code to understand why some rows would remain "empty", as you say... I would propose you try what I already shared with you and give me feedback whether that solves the issue, or not?

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to solve this problem. The above answer should work but you should probably add an id column symbolising which pair each row belongs to and add that to the on list in the merge call: on=["id", "col1", "col2", "col3"] to avoid false matches.

My solution is more intuitive for me since pass checks on same row are easier to perform. See code below:

```
# Convert Obs columns to numeric. Dont know which dataformat you are working with so this might not be necessary.
df.Obs = df.Obs.astype("int32")

# Insert id column to keep track of row pairs
df.insert(0, column="id", value=((df.Obs - 1) // 2) + 1)

# Pivot dataframe
df_pivoted = df.pivot(index="id", columns="Dataset", values=["Col1", "Col2", "Col3"])
df_pivoted.columns = [ col + "_" + val for col, val in df_pivoted.columns ]


pass_mask = (df_pivoted.Col1_Source == df_pivoted.Col1_Target) & (df_pivoted.Col2_Source == df_pivoted.Col2_Target) & (df_pivoted.Col3_Source == df_pivoted.Col3_Target)
df_pass = df_pivoted.assign(
    passed = pass_mask
)
```

I now this solution has another output format but I think this format is clearer. If you disagree its entirely possible to convert it back to original format. I hope this helps!